# C++/CLI - URL Download to File

Tags: c++, url, download, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm not entirely familiar with how CLI works, but I have a general idea. I have a function that takes 2 System::String variables, and uses those to download a file from a webpage. As far as the download goes, it works fine, and the file shows up in my directory with the necessary content. However, it gives me the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in ParseLinks.exe

```
void downloadFile(System::String ^_URL, System::String ^_saveAs)
{
    try
    {
        System::Net::WebClient ^webClient = gcnew System::Net::WebClient();
        // Downloads the resource with the specified URI to a local file.
        webClient->DownloadFile(_URL, _saveAs);
        webClient->Dispose();
    }
    catch (System::Exception ^_e)
    {
        // Error
        System::Console::WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _e);
    }
}
```

I did some digging and output testing, and found out that the exe is hitting a break point somewhere in the text file, as the entire webpage did not save to the txt file.

Relevant code for that:

```
        if (myFile.is_open()) //if file open
        {
            while (!myFile.eof()) //before end of file
            {
                getline(myFile, ln);
                lines[count] = ln;
                count++; //count total lines to set loop length for later parsing
                //Error occurs somewhere in here
            }
            myFile.close();
        }
        else
            cout<<"Error: Could not access file\n";
```

Brand New Error! :(

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in ParseLinks.exe

The code after the file -> line array loop

```
myFile.close(); //Close txt file

            //Loop through lines
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string temp = parseLinks(lines[i]); //parse links from each line
```

The function for that:

```
string parseLinks(string str)
{
    const int len = str.length();
    string link;
    bool quotes = false, islink = false;
    string compare[5] = {".htm",".html",".php",".asp",".pdf"};

    //Parse all quoted text
    for (int i = 0; i != len; i++)
    {
        //Change bool if quote found
        if (str[i] == '"')
        {
            if (quotes == false)
                quotes = true;
            else
                quotes = false;
        }

        //If bool true, and char is not a quote, add to link string
        if (quotes == true && str[i] != '"')
            link += str[i];
    }

    //Discard non-link text
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Link check for links given array of path filetypes
        if (link.compare((link.length() - compare[i].length()),compare[i].length(),compare[i]) == 0)
            islink = true;
    }
    //Link check for links with no path filetype (.html, .php, etc.)
    if (link.compare(0,7,"http://") == 0)   
        islink = true;

    //If not a link, return empty string
    if (islink == false)
        link = "";

    return link;
}
```

The error points to my large compare statement in this function. (Also, I'm clearly terrible at compressing my code)

Comment: What is `lines`, and how is it initialized?

Comment: It's the array I use for each line of text. I'm taking each line of text from the file, stuffing it in an array (for looping purposes), then shooting each line to a function in order to determine if it contains a link. For each link found, it shoots it into a 2nd array for links. (it ignores duplicates and external websites) For each link in the link array, it re-performs the entire process, going to that website, downloading the page, parsing the links, and adding them to an array. It's basically a crude website crawler.


Also, oops: I only initialized both arrays to 100 elements, thanks!

Comment: Not having it all saved **does not** mean the error is partway through the save process. It very well could be, but the system usually buffers file writes and an access violation (if it leads to program termination) can make the "written" (but really just buffered) data vanish into thin air.

Comment: I eventually ended up figuring out the 2nd error. It was related to trying to compare the found link with another variable of a certain length, when the found link was not at least as long as the variable it was trying to be compared to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getline` wrong, and possibly that's causing your error. The correct idiom is this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myFile, line))
{
  // process `line`
}
```

There's no need to check `myFile` for openness separately.

Comment: Thanks, that solved that error, but now I've got another one. >_<

As soon as I dig up more info I'll post it.